# Swap parts of filenames

Tags: rename, batch-rename

#### Problem

I have thousands folders, which names are structured like:
`firstName_lastName_date`
for which I want to swap the two first parts using the underscore `_` as a separator in order to end up with:
`lastName_firstName_date`

#### Warning

`lastName` may be be preceded by a [nobiliary particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobiliary_particle), separated with an extra `_` in the input folders.
For example:
`firstName_de_lastName_date`
`firstName_von_lastName_date`

For which the wanted output should be:
`de_lastName_firstName_date`
`von_lastName_firstName_date`

#### Information

- `date` is always the last element.
- First names are single words.
- Last names are single words or composed words (2) with a particle.

#### Tools

I want to do that using `rename` in bash, preferably, or [shell Parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

#### References

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

Comment: Can a last name have multiple parts in addition to the particle? Or a first name? Can you have something like `Jose_Maria_de_los_lobos_y_garcia_date`? Or can we be sure there will _always_ be either 3 or 2 `_` and whatever is between the 1st and last `_` will be the last name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it using the Perl-based `rename` I think, using a mix of non-greedy and greedy matches ex.

```
$ rename -n 's/^(.*?)_(.*)_(.*?)$/$2_$1_$3/' *
rename(firstName_de_lastName_date, de_lastName_firstName_date)
rename(firstName_lastName_date, lastName_firstName_date)
rename(firstName_von_lastName_date, von_lastName_firstName_date)
```

The non-greedy modifier on the last (`date`) group isn't really necessary - but I like the symmetry.

Alternatively, with the shell alone

```
$ for f in *; do 
    m="${f#*_}"; m="${m%_*}"; echo mv -- "$f" "${m}_${f%%_*}_${f##*_}";
  done
mv -- firstName_de_lastName_date de_lastName_firstName_date
mv -- firstName_lastName_date lastName_firstName_date
mv -- firstName_von_lastName_date von_lastName_firstName_date
```